# What does "hard angles" mean when describing a person's character?

Tags: expressions

I'm reading this novel, and there's a passage I don't quite understand.
It describes a heroine's character, and goes as below:]

> She is a smart, gorgeous chameleon, all heart and hard angles.

Specifically, I can't figure out what "all heart and hard angles" mean.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Thank you, Marria, for your answer. I didn't think I would get a reply this quick. You've helped me a lot!

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=JQpDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT91&dq=She+is+a+smart,+gorgeous+chameleon,+all+heart+and+hard+angles.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsp9-E9oDmAhUOup4KHdW3AxEQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=She%20is%20a%20smart%2C%20gorgeous%20chameleon%2C%20all%20heart%20and%20hard%20angles.&f=false

Answer (score 2):

I think it refers to **chameleon** part of the sentence, which means instability of the character. So she sometimes can be **all heart** (kind and caring) and sometimes - **all hard angles** (cold or even hostile).

I would describe this **all heart and hard angles** as **[tsundere](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tsundere)** type of person.

Comment: I agree that it's sometimes one and sometimes the other (which describes the chameleonism) , but I think it's comparing just (1) *heart* and (2) *hard angles*. To say that somebody is *all heart* is a very common expression. To describe somebody or something as *(all) hard angles* is not as common, but still common nonetheless. I have never before heard the expression *heart angles*.

Comment: Thank you, have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Jason and Mariia for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

"Heart and hard angles" is epigrammatic.  Though *heart* and *hard* have contrasting senses, they sound alike, so juxtaposing them is a lyrical device to explain *chameleon*.

Comment: Thank you, JMR, for your additional explanation:)